# Selecting rows from two nump.nd arrays and insert 0 for the missing match

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two nd.numpy arrays named 'a' and 'b', I want to select only certain rows from array 'b' based on the comparison with 'a' and insert 0 for the rows if a match is not found. I did the first part. eg;

```
a = np.array([[1,5,9],
           [2,6,10],
           [5,14,10]])

b = np.array([[ 1,0,9],
              [2,6,10],
              [4,6,10]])
```

output

```
[[ 1  0  9]
 [ 2  6 10]]
```

expected output

```
[[ 1  0  9]
 [ 2  6 10]
 [ 0  0  0]]
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
wanted= a[:,[0]]
y=b[np.logical_or.reduce([b[:,0] == x for x in wanted])]
print y
```

In the above example from the array 'a', in row '3' we don't have value '5' in array 'b', So when comparing 'a' with 'b' if a no match is found I want to insert '0' to the third row so that the dimension of the two arrays are equal.

Comment: I don't understand your match criterion: the `[1, 5, 9]` row doesn't match either (`b` has `[1, 0, 9]`); why is that one included?

Comment: for example in my wanted list I retrive the values of the first column of a [[1],[2],[5]] and compare with first column b which is [[1],[2],[4]], for value '1' and '2' there is a match so those values are retrived in the y, there is no match for 5 in row 3, so i want to insert '0' row 3 of array 'b'

Answer (score 1):

If you would like any element of `b[:, 0]` that is not in `a[:, 0]` to be zero you can do the following:

```
>>> b[~np.in1d(b[:, 0], a[:, 0]), :] = 0
>>> b
array([[ 1,  0,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 0,  0,  0]])
```

If you would like any element of `b[:, 0]` that is not in the corresponding row of `a` to be zero:

```
>>> b[~np.any(b[:, 0][:,None]==a, axis=1), :] = 0
>>> b
array([[ 1,  0,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 0,  0,  0]])
```